# Grouping data into bins

Tags: python, pandas

I want to subset the following data frame `df` into bins of a size 50:

```
    ID      FREQ
0   358081  6151
1   431511  952
2   410632  350
3   398149  220
4   177791  158
5   509179  151
6   485346  99
7   536655  50
8   389180  51
9   406622  45
10  410191  112
```

The result should be this one:

```
FREQ_BIN    QTY_IDs
>200        3
150-200     2
100-150     1
50-100      3
<50         1
```

How can I do it? Should I use `groupBy` or any other approach?

Comment: If you are  fine with using numpy then [`numpy.digitize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) would be an obvious choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`pd.cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html).

```
df.groupby(pd.cut(df.FREQ, 
                  bins=[-np.inf, 50, 100, 150, 200, np.inf], 
                  right=False)
           ).size()
```

`right=False` ensures that we take half-open intervals as your output suggests, and unlike [`np.digitize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) we need to include `np.inf` in the bins for "infinite endpoints".

**Demo**

```
>>> df.groupby(pd.cut(df.FREQ, 
                      bins=[-np.inf, 50, 100, 150, 200, np.inf], 
                      right=False)
               ).size()

FREQ
[-inf, 50)    1
[50, 100)     3
[100, 150)    1
[150, 200)    2
[200, inf)    4
dtype: int64
```